# How to rewrite the post URL according to the category?

Tags: categories, customization, permalinks

I have 1000 posts in my website, half of them are in difference categories and another half is in category called "blog". Current permalink structure is: http://xxxxx.com/articles/%postname% - this is for all posts. Now if category is blog then permalink should be like this: http://xxxx.com/blog/%author%/%postname% is there a way to do like this?